# MVC5 action without refreshing timeout

Tags: javascript, cookies, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity

I am using MVC5, EF6, AspNet Identity 2.0.
The views need to periodically check server for new notificiations, this is done by javascript/jquery get periodically reading a server side GET action.
Unfortunatelly, even the action having [AllowAnonymous], I found that action executes "OnValidateIdentity", I mean that sometimes the cookie expiration timeout is refreshed.

If the user just keep the page open, the logon will never expire... This is bad.

I read that javascript/jquery can't send a cookieless request. Seems that MVC5 server-side it is impossible to ignore the cookie in determined action.

I'm stuck... Any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found that best way is to use SignalR to notify the open pages about new notifications.
Javascript pool reading a server side GET action is not so smart, as it consumes more resources.